# Type 'undefined[]' cannot be converted to type 'OrderArray'. Property 'menuName' is missing in type 'undefined[]'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

### Goal

Hi, I am creating a restaurant ordering app. I am able to read an observable list from firebase. Now I want to use ion-select to each menu to assign the number of quantity someone wants to order.

[image: order menu]

### Problem

For now, I just want to assign the **quantity** of order to a model. I have created a model of a menu order, called **OrderArray**, and I want to have this model as an **Array**. This is the model `order-array.ts`:

```
export interface OrderArray {
  $key?: string,
  menuName: string,
  menuPrice: string,
  quantity: string
}
```

Then I want to convert this array to string, and assign it to another model named **Order**. This is the model `order.ts`:

```
export interface Order {
  custName: string,
  custPhone: string,
  restoName: string,
  restoPhone: string,
  restoAddress: string,
  message: string,
  orderArray: string
 // timestamp: number
}
```

The problem comes when I load the page:

> Type 'undefined[]' cannot be converted to type 'OrderArray'. Property
>   'menuName' is missing in type 'undefined[]'

```
public orderArray = [] as OrderArray;
```

and another error

> Type 'OrderArray' is not assignable to type 'string'.

```
this.order.orderArray = this.orderArray;
```

### My Code

This is the **order-menu.ts**

```
import { Order } from './../../models/order';
import { OrderArray } from './../../models/order-array';
.
.
.
public orderArray = [] as OrderArray;
.
.
.
this.order.orderArray = this.orderArray;
```

and this is the **order-menu.html**

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>OrderMenu</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let data of menuData | async ; let i = index ">
      <div item-content>
        <h2>Menu Name: {{data.payload.val().menuName}}</h2>
        <p>Price: {{data.payload.val().menuPrice}}</p>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>
            Jumlah Porsi:
          </ion-label>
          <ion-select [(ngModel)]="orderArray[i]">
            <ion-option value="1">1</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="2">2</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
      </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <ion-item item-content>
    <ion-label floating>Catatan</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="order.message"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <button ion-button (click)="orderMenu()">Order</button>

</ion-content>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `orderArray: string` orderArray is string  so `this.order.orderArray = this.orderArray;` will throw error

Comment: should be `public orderArray: OrderArray[] = []` so you won't get the `undefined` error

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jacopo Sciampi for the answer.

Instead of

```
public orderArray = [] as OrderArray;
```

I should use

```
public orderArray: OrderArray[] = []
```

Then 
Instead of

```
this.order.orderArray = this.orderArray;
```

I should use

```
this.order.orderArray = this.orderArray.toString();
```